# CSS - Creating a button the height of an entire column

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a button that stretches the height of a neighboring table column? Is it possible to stretch the button if it were an image?

I'll try to describe what I'm trying to do in layout below - one of the columns is simply a button, the other contains text and other data.

```
______   ______
|    |   |    |
|    |   |    |
|    |   |    |
|    |   |    |
|    |   |    |
______   ______
```

Comment: Can you only use CSS, or is javascript / jquery an option.  Obviously JS disabled broswers would see a different sized image, but would that be acceptable?

Comment: CSS-only preferred, but if failproof precision placement is possible with js/jquery I'd like to see a snippet of that, too!

Comment: Did you try using height: 100%?

Comment: height 100% won't work unless the parent elemnt has defined height.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a button that stretches the height of the neighboring column with `CSS` only, but you need to put both of them inside of a parent `<div>`. Then you add `display: flex`

```css
.mainContainer{
  display: flex;
}

.content{
  height: 200px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="content">
   This has content
  </div>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```